# CountDownTimer (error <identifier> expected) Invalid method declaration

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have here my code. I want to create a CountDownTimer but i got identifier expected in new CountDownTimer. My code is here. Can someone help?

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button sendBtn;
    TextView mTextField;
    EditText txtphoneNo;
    EditText txtMessage;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actividade_layout);

        sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
        txtphoneNo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhoneNo);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSMS);

        sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendSMSMessage();
            }
        });

    }

    protected void sendSMSMessage() {
        Log.i("Send SMS", "");

        String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
        String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

     new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            mTextField.setText("done!");
        }
    }.start();

}
```

My Countdown timer must be outside MainActivity function or can it be inside that function?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `CountDownTimer` outside of a method. Moreover, you are using the uninitialized member `mTextField`.